# Load htaccess from other directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, webserver

I have a directory in my server "/vol/apache/www/html/sites" and inside it I have about 300 websites hosted like:

```
"/vol/apache/www/html/sites/fdsfds.com"
"/vol/apache/www/html/sites/gfgdfggdfgd.net"
"/vol/apache/www/html/sites/ioiu43kkjflkdsjfldskj4.com.br"
...
```

I use VHOSTS to map every domain to the directory of that website like above.

Said that, I have a mod_rewrite rule to redirect users from www -> non-www and I placed that rule inside an .htaccess file inside "apache/www/html/sites/.htaccess".

The problem is that it is not having any effect. Only when I move the ".htaccess" to every site folder it works. Apache should be reading every .htaccess from the root "/vol/apache/www/html/" till the directories below.

It's not a problem with Allowoverride. It is all ok. I just want to know how to make apache read th htaccess in the root and AFTER that read the htaccess inside every website directory (if exists one).

Comment: Ok, you are right but in HG I have the same directory structure and it reads the htaccess in the /sites/ folder! So what is wrong?